# How to recover data lost during aborted local drag and drop?

Tags: data-recovery

I have dragged and dropped a large amount of data between two tabs of Thunar (XFCE 4.10) but accidentally clicked cancel during the process.

The data have been removed from the source folder and are of course incomplete on the destination folder.

The source and the destination folder are on the same partition (ext4) of the same disk (so a bit different from [File damaged/lost during transfer?  Recovery possible?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19539/file-damaged-lost-during-transfer-recovery-possible)).

I haven't touched anything since. The Thunar "free space" indicator still acts like the data are here.

What can I try ? Why did it even move the data on the first place ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution** : Just reselect the remaining source from it's root folder, and then copy it in the destination, unless there are already folders with the same name. This will complete the copy and once finished you'll discover all your data is there.

**Explanation** : When files/folders are moved using a GUI filemanager like Thunar or Nautilus nothing is supposed to be removed before it was entirely copied to the destination.
If you break the process before it completes the operation you feel like a part of the Data is lost because you find some directories don't contain all data witch was there before. But if you look at the destination you can find the missing part of data.