# Does "mount -o remount,ro" flush filesystem buffers?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, buffer

On Linux, does `mount -o remount,ro` flush filesystem buffers/cache, or should I also run `sync` to achieve that?

Comment: Yes, unless the `remount` is combined with a `bind`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *should* flush the cache, yes.

Arguably there is some fragility in this code path.  It is not implemented in one place; it is implemented in each individual filesystem.  E.g. [ext2_remount() must call sync_filesystem()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/fs/ext2/super.c#L1325).

Also in all the use cases that I know of, it is used together with the `sync()` system call.  So if you rely on this, and the kernel gets it wrong, you might have the "privilege" of being the first to notice a problem.

If you want to be extra-careful, you could use `sync -f /my/mounted/filesystem/`.  It is preferable to `sync` because it avoids interference with any other filesystem.  It uses the Linux system call `syncfs()`.

Comment: The same _should_ be true for [xfs filesystems](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/fs/xfs/xfs_super.c#L1270)

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sync_%28Unix%29)

> Buffers are also flushed when filesystems are unmounted or remounted read-only, for example prior to system shutdown.

Comment: Thank you, but can you quote a better source than Wikipedia?

Comment: This quote is currently marked [citation needed].  The quote is also wrong, because it is not true for some non-Linux systems.  "According to the standard specification (e.g., POSIX.1-2001), sync()
       schedules the writes, but may return before the actual writing is
       done." http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html This was a problem on historical UNIX: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/416466/29483